# javascript: add span around last two characters

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I need to put a span around the last two characters within a div.

The current structure looks like this:

```
<div id="price">3199</div>
```

I need to output something like this:

```
<div id="price">31<span id="smaller">99</span></div>
```

It's for a price in a dynamic HTML5 banner ad. I need the ability to format the final two characters smaller than the first two, but the integer from the dynamic feed is simply 3199 or 2099 etc. etc.

I've found some jQuery solutions but I need this to be plain JavaScript.

**[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kF7LK/)**  solves it well with jQuery, and I'm sure it doesn't need much tweaking to work without jQuery but my javascript skills can't quite crack it.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: just updated the question to include a jquery fiddle

Comment: see jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/akf5vm1k/

Comment: @jeff Fiddle script does not work?

Comment: @Thaillie, much like your fiddle 'doesn't work' - right :-)

Comment: @jeff Lets word it different then, firefox does not support `innerText`. So thats why it does not work for me. Firefox uses `.textContent` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: `id=smaller` is not semantic. A better option is `class="decimal"`

Comment: that makes sense @JuanMendes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with regex **[`.{2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/sF6wT6/1)**

```js
var ele=document.getElementById('price');
ele.innerHTML=ele.innerHTML.replace(/.{2}$/,'<span id="smaller">$&</span>')
```

```css
#smaller{
font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="price">3199</div>
```

Comment: This works in this case because of the simple example. However, if you have any handlers applied to that HTML, they will be lost (orphaned). See my answer for a solution that doesn't affect handlers that were already set so it can be used without worrying http://stackoverflow.com/a/33127913/227299

Comment: Yes, for example: `<div><span class="wholeamount">24</span>99</div>`. And you had a handler on `wholeamount`. [This fiddle shows the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/16nnkhmc/) (move your mouse over the 24) [This other fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/yupaox0q/) shows how my solution would not break the existing handler

Comment: Pranav, I understand it's not a problem in this case, I just don't want people to use your solution blindly because there are cases where it doesn't work. It's a hack that is suitable for highly controlled cases, but you need to be careful. Code always evolve and this could cause a problem in the future.

Comment: This solution worked best for my purposes, but @JuanMendes answer below is worth taking into consideration under different circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Exaple using `substring`, not as nice as regex but works.

```js
var str = document.getElementById('price').innerHTML;
cut = str.substring(str.length, 2);
document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = str.slice(0, -2) + '<span id="smaller">' + cut + '</span>';
```

```css
#smaller{
font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="price">3199</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6d3sozu7/)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have event handlers on that HTML, you can't just reset `innerHTML`, you have to use a more foolproof of breaking up text nodes, using DOM manipulation.

```js
var priceNode = document.getElementById('price');
var textNode = priceNode.firstChild;
var newTextNode = textNode.splitText(textNode.data.length - 2); // Index of where to break the text node
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'decimal';
span.appendChild(newTextNode);
priceNode.appendChild(span);
```

```css
.decimal {
   font-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="price">3199</div>
```

Here's a case where innerHTML manipulation breaks an existing handler

```js
$('.wholeamount').hover(
  function(){ $(this).addClass('highlight')},
  function(){ $(this).removeClass('highlight')}   
);

$('button').click(function() {
  var ele=document.getElementById('price');
  ele.innerHTML=ele.innerHTML.replace(/.{2}$/,'<span class="decimal">$&</span>')
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.decimal {
    font-size: 50%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>Hover over the 24 to see it highlight</pre>
<div id="price"><span class="wholeamount">24</span>.99</div> <hr />
<button>Make decimal</button>
<pre>The highlight will be gone when you manipulate innerHTML</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `slice` function to edit the `innerHTML`

This is the cleanest way to do it.

```
var ele=document.getElementById('price');
ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML.slice(0, 2) + "<span id='smaller'>" + ele.innerHTML.slice(2) + "</span>";
```